# Windows 10 revert to Win8 to reset key activation

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, windows-activation, reset, downgrade

I am currently in a computer crisis. I just updated my PC to Windows 10. The problem occurred during the activation of the Windows 10 Pro and Family key. Microsoft Support tells me what are blocked for one reason or another. The solution they gave me is to downgrade to the original OS (Windows 8.1) and then reinstall Windows 10.

The "Rollback" feature on Windows 10 does not work. So I contacted once again the support center, and then told me to go ask to the manufacturer (HP), to provide me a copy of Windows 8.1 (or how to install it......). Note that my PC has UEFI protection, so I can not run a boot drive.   I will be very grateful if you fix my problem. Thank you, 3751_Creator

Comment: There is absolutely no reason you cannot boot to a EFI boot disk. You are going to have to do this if you want to revert to Windows 8.1.  Please clarify with regards to `Windows 10 Professional and Family` that isn't a version of Windows 10 I am familiar with.  Windows 8 installation was legitimate correct?

Comment: @Ramhound How do I get a Win8 boot?

Comment: Use the tool provided by Microsoft if its a retail license.  Otherwise talk to HP about getting an installation disk.